# How do I add a loop to this program and have it keep running until program is true?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop

How and where do I add a loop to this program so that the program keeps executing then ends once the user has enter a valid number between 100 and 999?

```
import java.util.*;

public class numLoop{
public static void main(String[] arg){
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  int number = 0;

  try{
     Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print("Enter a number between 100 and 999: ");
     number = reader.nextInt();

     if(number > 999 || number < 100)
        System.out.println("\nYour number was invalid.");

     else
        System.out.println("\nThe number " + number + " was vaild.");

      }
      catch(InputMismatchException ime){
            System.out.println("You didn't enter a number.");

     }
 }
}
```

Comment: Search for do / while structure.

Comment: You're looking for a [while loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html).

Comment: implement a `while` loop

Answer (score 1):

Put your whole try/catch inside a `while` loop:

```
while (number < 100 || number > 999)
{
    // ...
}
```

Or put it in an infinite loop using `while (true) { }` or `for (;;) { }` and then add a conditional `break` if a valid number is entered:

```
if (number < 100 || number > 999)
{
    // handle invalid entry
}

else
{
    // handle valid entry

    break; // exit loop
}
```

Comment: Please, not for (;;) :)

Comment: no need to double check the validity of number 

+ using while(true) and break is a really bad practice

Comment: @AndreaGirardi Why? That's always been my favorite infinite loop style, and I just had a conversation with a coworker about it a couple weeks ago, so I'm curious what your reasons are :)

Comment: @faboul I'm not; the two sections of code I posted were two different alternatives, not to be combined.

Comment: It works fine, but I just don't like it. I prefer something like while ( condition ) {} . Just personal opinion :) It should be a waste of memory to declare a variable to be used on condition, but it's how I like to do. And now, I'm curious about the conclusion of discussion with your colleague

Comment: @AndreaGirardi I guess we agreed to disagree. I like `for (;;)` because it's fewer keystrokes, it's "purer" (`for` uses a termination condition, which can be empty, whereas `while` uses a continuation condition which requires you to put something in there, i.e. `true`). My coworker finds `while (true)` more readable and clear, which is probably true, but I think being able to read and understand `for (;;)` is a pretty safe expectation for professional programmers. I guess you're right, it's a lot of personal preference. Being fewer keystrokes is a good enough reason alone for me.

Comment: @DavidNorris agree with you, but, after read your comment, I think I'll re-consider the for (;;) althorugh I'm still agree also with your colleague, it's more readable (of course in my opinion)

Answer (score 1):

Using a `while` loop you can implement the following logic

(pseudocode)

```
Input a number
while (number is not valid)
    Tell them something went wrong
    Input another number
Valid number was entered, do something about it
```

The while loop itself looks like

```
while (condition) {
   // code to run while condition is true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class numLoop{
public static void main(String[] arg){
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  int number = 0;

  try{
     Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print("Enter a number between 100 and 999: ");
     number = reader.nextInt();

     while(number > 999 || number < 100){
        System.out.println("\nYour number was invalid.");
        number = reader.nextInt();
     }

     System.out.println("\nThe number " + number + " was vaild.");


      }catch(InputMismatchException ime){
            System.out.println("You didn't enter a number.");

     }
 }
}
```

Comment: ...some compilation error here! Missing a } before catch and, of course, not sure it's actually an answer of the submitted question

Comment: fixed, I answered too fast, and thus misplaced a curly bracket

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a while(true) break loop like this:

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class numLoop{
    public static void main(String[] arg){
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      int number = 0;
    while(true){
      try{
         Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.print("Enter a number between 100 and 999: ");
         number = reader.nextInt();

         if(number > 999 || number < 100)
            System.out.println("\nYour number was invalid.");

         else
            System.out.println("\nThe number " + number + " was vaild.");
            break;
          }
          catch(InputMismatchException ime){
                System.out.println("You didn't enter a number.");

         }
     }
    }
  }
```

Be warned trough not everyone things this is good code practice.

Answer (score 0):

Three little lines... before your existing `try` add

```
while(true) // you could (and should) add braces (for the look of it).
            // could also have used for(;;)
```

And here

```
else
  System.out.println("\nThe number " + number + " was vaild.");
```

You then need a

```
else {
  System.out.println("\nThe number " + number + " was vaild.");
  break;  // End the infinite loop.
}
```